# What are some counterexamples that prove using {} for find is not safe?

Tags: unix, find

I have been always using

```
find ... -exec .... '{}' \;
```

Are there counterexamples that prove the variants

```
find ... -exec .... {} \;
find ... -exec .... "{}" \;
```

can cause problems on some UNIX-based OS (Ubuntu Linux, macOS, etc.)?

Comment: This is not a problem of Unix variant but a matter of shell syntax.